# Arduino Pinging an IP

Tags: arduino, hardware, icmp

I'm trying to make and arduino project that pings a static ip for my phone and up receiving a response, opens my door. I've managed to a library (available [here](https://github.com/BlakeFoster/Arduino-Ping)) that allows for this, but it, along with the default ethernet library are both based on the Wiznet W5100 chip, while the shield I have is based on the W5200 library. I can find an updated ethernet library that handles the different chip, but the ping library can't recognize it. Can anybody recommend where I should start making modifications, or if they know of a library that allows the new chipset to successfully ping an known ip?

Comment: why do you need ping on an arduino?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem with W5100 chip, the `Arduino-Ping` library that you mentioned always had errors during compile. Finally I fixed it. The problem was caused by the default `Ethernet` library that  is installed in Arduino folder. I used [WIZ Ethernet Library](https://github.com/Wiznet/WIZ_Ethernet_Library) that WIZNET has developed it for their chips. I deleted the default `Ethernet` library in arduino library folder and installed `WIZ Ethernet Library` based on my chip number through this link and now every thing works fine.